# Partially replace value of key-val pair in an object

Tags: javascript

Given I have the following object:

```
let obj = { 
    cat: "paws",
    dogs: {
        lab: "Christopher",
        otherLab: "Lady Buba"
    }
}

let objTwo = {
    dogs: {
        lab: "some new name"
    }
}
```

How can I merge the above two objects so that the final result is:

```
{
    cat: "paws",
    dogs: {
        lab: "some new name",
        otherLab: "Lady Buba"
    }
}
```

I've attempted to use spread operators with `let finalObj = {...obj, ...objTwo}`, but this entirely replaces the value of dogs, so that the end result is:

```
{
    cat: "paws",
    dogs: {
        lab: "some new name",
    }  
}
```

which isn't what I want.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: As per the question, I attempted using spread operators, which didn't work.

Comment: Ow sorry, misread. You can spread the dogs object to get the desired outcome: `obj.dogs = { ...obj.dogs, ...objTwo.dogs }`

Comment: Spread does a shallow replace; you want a deep one. If you know that they replacement occurs at the `dogs` level, just replace that: `let finalObj = { obj.cat, dogs: { ...obj.dogs, ...objTwo.dogs } };`.

Comment: this will solve your problem ```const result = { ..obj, dogs: {...obj.dogs, ...objTwo.dogs}}```